# passing variable into class functions and use it

Tags: php, function, class, oop, variables

i got one class and i'm trying to implement it into my website, but i'm unable to pass variable into it...

```
class Order {

   var $totalPrice = null;

   function load() {
      $this->totalPrice = 123;
   }

   function loadByPaymentSessionId($paymentSessionId) {
       $this->totalPrice = 123;
   }
}

$order = new Order();
$order->load();
```

How can i set $this->totalPrice outside of class?

Comment: Pass it through constructor, or create a `setTotalPrice` method? And please, change this `var $totalPrice` either by `public` if you *really* need it to be or `protected`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment your property is given public access, so:

```
$order->totalPrice = 4.65;
```

Alternatively, if you want the ability to set the price at the point of instantiation you could provide a constructor with an argument:

```
class Order {

    public $totalPrice;

    public function __construct($totalPrice = null)
    {
        $this->totalPrice = $totalPrice;
    }
}

$order = new Order(4.85);
```

Or, if you need to perform some kind of logic while the value is set, you could prevent direct access to the class member and provide an accessor method:

```
class Order {

    private $totalPrice;

    public function setTotalPrice($totalPrice)
    {  
        $this->totalPrice = (float) $totalPrice;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to make `$totalPrice` private, and set him by function like this:

```
function load2($newVal) {
      //some validation
      $this->totalPrice = $newVal;
   }
```